# Locating Serialization Issue in Complex Bean

Tags: java, serialization

I have a large bean graph that I'm trying to serialize.  Getting serialization exception (a non-specific one).  Anyone have a class that will help locate the issue?

Comment: See [Java flag to enable extended Serialization debugging info
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660441/java-flag-to-enable-extended-serialization-debugging-info)

Answer (score 14):

From JDK6 you should be able to get extra information by setting the sun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo system property:

```
-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true
```

Comment: where to set this flag in tomcat server?

Comment: @eatSleepCode It's probably worth creating a separate question about how set system properties/pass `-D` flags on Tomcat. I once would have been able to tell you. To not answer your question, it's always worth investing in [automated] testing, which would make such a problem disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Write one or more unit tests that serialize parts of the graph or the full graph. This will let you brak the problem into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a special output stream that will perform some additional checks. See [this page](http://crazybob.org/2007/02/debugging-serialization.html) as a reference.