# Java flag to enable extended Serialization debugging info

Tags: java, debugging, serialization, flags

I am currently struggling with HTTP Session replication on tomcat with complex objects.

Some objects implement `Serializable` but hold non-serializable members.

Unfortunately, the stacktraces do not provide much useful info here by default.

**there is a flag -XX:???? to enable verbose class names** in the stacktrace when a NotSerializableException occurrs. this flag would help me a lot finding the source of the error. but i forgot its name

What is the name of the flag?

Comment: By session, do you mean a Servlet `HttpSession`?

Comment: yes. HttpSession must only contain serializable objects or else it won't persist restart and won't be able to be replicated to other tomcat nodes..

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> -Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true

Comment: I need to wait 2 days before i can mark this as accepted, due to SO rules. i found the answer at http://mfondo.blogspot.com/2007/10/java-serialization-debugging.html

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this flag only kicks in when there is a serialization problem, as a result the logs won't go crazy before the event occurs.

Comment: @AndreasPetersson  where to set this? like I am using tomcat server

Comment: @eatSleepCode The command line for starting Tomcat. It's a Java parameter, so it needs to be placed into the java command.