# What makes an Object serializable

Tags: java, file, serialization

I have an object with a `HashMap` field and a few methods that I am trying to serialize. However, at runtime, I am getting a `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

I was checking to see if `HashMaps` could be serialized and from what I have read they are so I am not sure what the problem is.

I was just wondering what makes an object be able to be serialized and why would this object that seems to only have fields that can be serialized not be able to as well.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Comment: What about objects being stored in the map? Do they implement 'Serializable' interface?

Comment: Useful, to show you exactly what can't be serialized: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660441/java-flag-to-enable-extended-serialization-debugging-info

Comment: @NoMercy I am only storing Strings and String arrays

Comment: @AndyTurner I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined in the Java platform Spec here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html

The basic rules are these:

"A Serializable class must do the following:

- Implement the java.io.Serializable interface
- Identify the fields that should be serializable (Use the
  serialPersistentFields member to explicitly declare them serializable
  or use the transient keyword to denote nonserializable
- Have access to the no-arg constructor of its first nonserializable
  superclass"

Broadly, in the absence of any indication to the contrary, and field that is not explicitly marked "transient" is a candidate for serialization.

The entire object graph from the target object downwards has to be serializable, or nothing is. That is, every field that references an object (not a primitive) must reference a serializable object.