# How to Serialize a Runnable to execute code on another infinispan node

Tags: java, lambda, runnable, serializable, infinispan

I am trying to execute some code on a member node of an infinispan cluster but I'm getting the same error all the time.

> **org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableException:**

The use case is pretty basic. There's a list of *units* only the coordinator node knows and wants to distribute some work among its member nodes.

Basically *I just want to call a method remotely with my args*. That's it, that's all, plain and simple.

```
private void processUnit(Unit unit)
{
  Processor.process(unit);
}

public void distributeUnits(List<Unit> units)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < units.size(); ++i)
  {
    Address target = getAddress(i);
    ClusterExecutor executor = getExecutor();
    executor.filterTargets(target).submit((Runnable & Serializable) () -> processUnit(unit);
  }
}
```

My goal would be the member node to execute the Runnable with the node context (its own *Processor*, which is an @Autowired spring @Component).

I have tried different approaches like statics here and there, classes extending and/or implementing Runnable, Serializable, etc. Last thing I've tried is to use the Observer pattern to instead of calling the Processor to call a static *OBSERVABLE.notifyObservers(unit)* (which has the Processor added as observer). But I've got the same output, and at this point its just trial and error. I'm out of ideas and I would appreciate some directions or guidelines on this.

Comment: The code you showed here will make the Runnable lambda Serializable as you want. However this lambda is capturing and the `unit` instance must also be Serializable. Make sure the Unit class or the implementation thereof is also Serializalable.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mudokonman wrote in his comment, the `(Runnable & Serializable)` syntax is find, but all the variables captured captured by the lambda must be `Serializable` as well. This includes the implicit `this` when the lambda invokes a non-static method.

You can try [`-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660441/java-flag-to-enable-extended-serialization-debugging-info) to find exactly which part of your lambda is not serializable.